# How to get auto generated value from composite primary key in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have 1 table with composite primary key from an auto-increase ID (refresh daily) and pass in value. I am using Hibernate for the DB process. May I know how can I retrieve the auto-increase ID value immediate after save?
I tried to get ID, but the auto-increase ID just showing me no value.

Code:

```
public class TableA implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private TableAPK id;

    @Id
    @EmbeddedId
    public TableAPK getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    ......
}

@Embeddable
public class TableAPK implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -335299619303934505L; 

    private int tableAId;
    private String value;

    public TableAPK() {
    }

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getTableAId() {
        return this.tableAId;
    }

    ...........
}


public Object persist(Session session, TableA entity) throws SystemException {
    Object id = null;
    try {
        id = session.save(entity);

    ......

    return id;
}

public void save(TableA entity) throws SystemException {
    Transaction trns = null;
    Session session = null;
    try {
        session = SessionUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        trns = session.beginTransaction();

        DaoInterface<TableA> dao = new TableADaoImpl();
        dao.persist(session, entity);   

        trns.commit();
        if (logger.isLoggable(Level.INFO)) {
            logger.info("Create New: ID: " + entity.getId().getTransId()
                    + ", Created time: " + entity.getId().getValue());
        }

    ...............
}
```

I tried to get the ID value after save as below
    TableAPK id = dao.persist(session, entity);
or add flush and refresh after save

```
dao.persist(session, entity);
session.flush;
session.refresh(entity)
```

but I still failed to retrieve the tableAId value.

Hope somebody can provide me some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which method of Hibernate are you using to **persist** the entity **save()** or **persist()**?
If you are using persist() then **persist() will never** give any value back to the client so Try This,

```
long id = session.save(entity);
```

If this is the method you are using to persist the entity

```
public Long persist(Session session, TableA entity) throws SystemException {
    Long id = null;
    try {
        id = session.save(entity);

    ......

    return id;
}
```

form where you are calling this method `public void save(TableA entity)`

Try this,

```
TableAPK tableAPK=new TableAPK();
tableAPK.setTableAId(....);
tableAPK.setValue(....);

TableA tableA=new TableA();
tableA.setId(tableAPK);
Object compositeId=session.save(tableA);
```

I have been hovering over all the possible links on World Wide Websites and trying to find why you cannot use @GeneratedValue with @EmbeddedId or @IdClass (i.e. composite PKs). The reason is that you just CANNOT.

Composite PKs are ASSIGNMENT-based not GENERATION-based. Therefore, any @GeneratedValue stuff are not supposed to work with them. I am also having problem in my project and I think there is no other way

If you know that your @GeneratedValue ID is always unique in context of your domain (for example, your database) you don't need to use composite PK and have some internal checks to determine the uniqueness of your records

Comment: Hi, I am using save() method, but my primary key is composite primary which is established by 1 auto generate integer and 1 string value.

Comment: Remove **@Id**  annotation from your TableA entity keep only  '@EmbeddedId'

Comment: I tried to remove and test, but still failed to retrieve the value. The workaround is re-query the data with non-id criteria for this moment.

Comment: You mentioned in your comment as 'composite primary which is established by 1 auto generate integer and 1 string value',It wont work if you are generating through auto generation.Because Composite PKs are ASSIGNMENT-based not GENERATION-based.