# Boot JPA Repository saveAndFlush with composite key

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am currently trying to to perform a persist using a JPARepository interface of a Credential object, that has a composite key as a primary key.
The repo is:

`@Transactional
         public interface CredentialRepository extends        JpaRepository<Credential,CredentialPK> {}`

The credentialPK is:

```
    @Embeddable
    public class CredentialPK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "CREDENTIAL_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer credentialID;

    @Column(name = "CREDENTIAL_TYPE_ID")
    private String credentialTypeID;

    public CredentialPK() {
    }
    //getters and setters;
```

}`

The credential :

     `@Entity
     @Table(name = "TBL_CREDENTIALS")
    public class Credential {
        @EmbeddedId
        private CredentialPK credentialPK;
        //getters and setters
    }`

In the service class, I am trying to perform a save operation using a credential type, that is provided by the application. Let's say that for the example's sake, the credential type is 'temporary'. 
The code for creating and persisting the credential is as follows:

```
     Credential credential = new Credential();
     CredentialPK pk = new CredentialPK(); 
     pk.setCredentialTypeID("temporary");
     credential.setCredentialPK(pk);
     Credential temporaryCredential =   credentialRepository.saveAndFlush(credential);

     temporaryCredential.getCredentialPK().getCredentialID(); // returns null, even when repository is flushed
```

`

I require that the **temporaryCredential** have the credentialID populated with the id of the freshly inserted credential. However, the credentialID i'm getting is null. I've tried using both **CrudRepository** api and **JpaRepository** api for the repository implementations, with both **save** and **saveAndFlush** methods. This works perfectly if the credential's primary key is not composite, but due to legacy code, I cannot make this change.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From another answer: [How to get auto generated value from composite primary key in hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30592497/how-to-get-auto-generated-value-from-composite-primary-key-in-hibernate)

> I have been hovering over all the possible links on World Wide Websites and trying to find why you cannot use @GeneratedValue with @EmbeddedId or @IdClass (i.e. composite PKs). The reason is that you just CANNOT.
>
> Composite PKs are ASSIGNMENT-based not GENERATION-based. Therefore, any @GeneratedValue stuff are not supposed to work with them. I am also having problem in my project and I think there is no other way
>
> If you know that your @GeneratedValue ID is always unique in context of your domain (for example, your database) you don't need to use composite PK and have some internal checks to determine the uniqueness of your records

So, like this poster said, if you have a `@GeneratedValue`, you don't need a composite PK, the generated value is unique. There will never be any combination of `creditialId` and `credentialTypeId` could be non-unique. This basically means you need to rethink your design, IMHO.

Comment: Thank you! Hopefully this will be made possible in the upcoming boot releases.