# composite Id dosen't changed after hibernate save

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a Report entity which is identified with a number (auto_increment) and an index.I have another entity Flyleaf which has the same identifier and there is a one-to-one association between the two entities ( (number, index) is a foreign key in the flyleaf table ). My code is :

```
public class ReportPK implements Serializable {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name="num")
    private int num;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name="report_index")
    private String index;
    ...(getters, setters, equals and hashCode)
}

@Entity
@Table(name="report")
public class Report {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ReportPK id;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
      @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="num", referencedColumnName="num"),
        @JoinColumn(name="report_index", referencedColumnName="report_index"),
      })
    private Flyleaf flyleaf;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="flyleaf")
public class Flyleaf  implements Serializable{

    @EmbeddedId
    private ReportPK id;
    ...
}
```

When I save a report, without setting its associated flyleaf, the code works and the report is added to database. However, when I try to save the flyleaf with the next code this exception is thrown "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`lgmi_cr`.`flyleaf`, CONSTRAINT `flyleaf_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`num`, `report_index`) REFERENCES `report` (`num`, `report_index`)).

```
Session session = getCurrentSession();
Report report = new Report();
ReportPK rpk = new ReportPK();
rpk.setIndex("A");
report.setId(rpk);
session.save (report);
//if I stop here the code works good and the num is auto_incremented in the data table
Flyleaf flyleaf = new Flyleaf();
flyleaf.setId(report.getId());
report.setFlyleaf(flyleaf);
```

I found out that the reason is that, after saving the report, its number (num of ReportPK) is not updated and it is equal to zero. And even through the next code the number is zero :

```
ReportPK pk = (ReportPK) session.save(report);
pk.getNum();
```

If some could help me and tell me where is the problem I will be thankful.

Note: I'm using MySQL database and spring framework

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get auto generated value from composite primary key in hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30592497/how-to-get-auto-generated-value-from-composite-primary-key-in-hibernate)

Answer (score 0):

Generated values are not possible with `@EmbeddedId` composite keys.  Embeddables are meant to be assigned values, therefore the use of `@GeneratedValue` is ignored here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In this case, my idea is to remove the @GeneratedValue annotation, disable num field  auto_incremented, add a field (let gen_field) to the table which is auto_incremented (not part  of the primary ke). When I want to save the report I will set num to 0 and index to A then I will retrieve value of gen_field and update the report num with this value.

Is this feasible?